# Datatables and ColumnFilterWidgets not working; need to strip HTML from filter select

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've got the [DataTables jQuery plugin](http://datatables.net/) working, and its plugin [ColumnFilterWidgets](https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets) successfully filters results in most cases.

I'm having an issue, however, when a cell/column I'm attempting to filter contains HTML - in my case, comma-delimited hyperlinks. The dropdown select is created correctly, but each option contains not only the text but the full hyperlink code. When the filter runs, it returns no results.

This problem has [apparently been around for a while](https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets/issues/3), but nothing I've tried has fixed it (including the fix in that thread).

This is my code where I initialize the datatable and set up the filters:

```
var oTable = $('#pub_table').dataTable( {
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "<h5><i class='icon-search icon-large'></i>&nbsp;Search Publications</h5>"
                },
                "sDom": 'W<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
                    "sSeparator": ", ",
                    "aiExclude": [ 0 ],
                    "bGroupTerms": true,
                }
            } );
```

My table code is php-generated but straightforward, this is an example of the resulting dataset which is being used by datatables:

```
<table id="pub_table" width="100%" class="pretty">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="resource_title">Resource</th>
        <th class="resource_libraries">Library</th>
        <th class="resource_audiences">Target Audience</th>
        <th class="resource_topics">Topic</th>
        <th class="resource_types">Type</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/resources/a-video-resource/" rel="bookmark" title="A video resource">A video resource</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/libraries/advocacy/" rel="tag">Advocacy</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/staff/" rel="tag">Staff</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/topics/sample-topic-2/" rel="tag">Sample topic 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/types/download/" rel="tag">Download</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/types/video/" rel="tag">Video</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/resources/social-media-guidelines-and-best-practices/" rel="bookmark" title="Social Media Guidelines and Best Practices">Social Media Guidelines and Best Practices</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/libraries/advocacy/" rel="tag">Advocacy</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/libraries/board-governance/" rel="tag">Board Governance</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/libraries/program-administration/" rel="tag">Program Administration</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/board-members/" rel="tag">Board Members</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/staff/" rel="tag">Staff</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/stakeholders/" rel="tag">Stakeholders</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/volunteers/" rel="tag">Volunteers</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/topics/sample-topic-1/" rel="tag">Sample topic 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/types/article/" rel="tag">Article</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/resources/brand-guidelines/" rel="bookmark" title="Brand Guidelines">Brand Guidelines</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/libraries/program-administration/" rel="tag">Program Administration</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/board-members/" rel="tag">Board Members</a>, <a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/audiences/staff/" rel="tag">Staff</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/topics/sample-topic-1/" rel="tag">Sample topic 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://mwamp.1505garnaas.net/texascasa/wp/blog/types/download/" rel="tag">Download</a></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th class="resource_title">Resource</th>
        <th class="resource_libraries">Library</th>
        <th class="resource_audiences">Target Audience</th>
        <th class="resource_topics">Topic</th>
        <th class="resource_types">Type</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I've searched extensively and haven't been able to figure this out. It doesn't help I'm fairly new to jQuery. :) Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Could an option be hiding an additional column that contained no html, then applying the filter to that hidden column? Ive done that before and can share code

Comment: Yes, I could do that (and have in the past) - just wishing there were a way to fix it without the hack. Seems like stripping the HTML should be do-able for someone with jQuery skillz. But if all else fails that's how I'll do it! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, i'll help try to figure this out, have you seen this? http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/41317#Comment_41317

Comment: NO!!! I had not seen that and don't know how I missed it - thank you!! It solves the issue perfectly. I'm going to go add that to the GitHub repo so it can be incorporated into the core at some point. Sheesh. :-) thanks again, if you want to put that down as the answer I'm happy to give you some cred...

Comment: ok, added an answer, glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your source to (courtesy of datatables forum http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/41317#Comment_41317)

```
for (var i = 0, c = aiRows.length; i < c; i++) {
           iRow = aiRows[i];
           sValue = $('<div>' + this.fnGetData(iRow, iColumn) + '</div>').text();
           // ignore empty values?
           if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

           // ignore unique values?
           else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

           // else push the value onto the result data array
           else asResultData.push(sValue);
       }
```